# Wordpress: Show three random posts on every page refresh

Tags: php, wordpress

In my WordPress, I am able to show one random post by using the below code:

```
global $post;

if ( post_type_exists( 'testimonial' ) ) { 

   $testimonial_query = new WP_Query( array(
       'post_type' => 'testimonial',
       'orderby' => 'rand',
       'posts_per_page' => -1
   ) );

   if ( $testimonial_query->have_posts() ) {
      $random_int = rand( 0, $testimonial_query->post_count - 1 );
      $post = $testimonial_query->posts[$random_int];     
      setup_postdata( $post );

      // do something with post - e.g. the_excerpt(), the_content(), etc.
   }
   // Restore original post data
   wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Ref: https://barn2.co.uk/how-to-display-a-random-post-in-wordpress/

Help me to show 3 random posts by using the above method.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using in array property or WP_Query. A sample code is given belwo

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE `post_type` = 'testimonial' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3" );
$ids     = array();
foreach($results as $$result){
    $ids[] = $results->ID;  
}

$args = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'testimonial' ),
    'orderby' => 'ASC',
    'post__in' => $ids
);

$testimonial_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```